# Pentaho - Increment when a value changes

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

I want to increment a value by 1 every time a value changes.

For example there may be 3 rows with the value 098290-IFS. Those rows will all have a value of 1 for the increment, but when the value changes to say, 017393-IFS, the value will increment to 2, and so on.

What transformation would I use to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the next step **Add value fields changing sequence**. This adds a number when the value changes, keep in mind that you may have to sort the flow to achieve the result you expect, you cant look this [enter link description here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Add+value+fields+changing+sequence),Regards

Comment: This step would reset the counter each time the input value changes and increment it when it doe not. This is just the opposite of what's asked.